# Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> while inserting figures

Tags: floats

```
\documentclass[aip,amsmath,amssymb,preprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx,graphics,dcolumn,bm,textcomp}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\includegraphics{conc}\caption{\label{figepsart} A figure caption. The figure captions are automatically numbered.}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using `fixltx2e`? That causes the error. Remove it. Also `graphics` isn't needed when you use `graphicx`.

Comment: Thank you!!. It works now, I was using fixltx2e for text subscript. Now I am using instead math environment ($_$) for subscript.

Comment: @HarishKumar Why not post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like an incompatibility inside the output routine stuff between package `fixltx2e` and class `revtex4-1`, if the package is loaded after the class. The other loading order seems to work:

```
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error without fixltx2e, it can be caused by having underscore symbols in your filename.  For example, instead of:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/static/beerfix2/beer_fix_2.png}
```

you need:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/static/beerfix2/beerfix2.png}
```